# Start activity from application context in another process

Tags: android, process

For starting activity outside activity context, we will use application context. Like applicationContext.startActivity(new Intent(TestActivity.class ....))

If the service which call startActivity is in another process, is the applicatioContext also belongs to another process? Will android create applicationContext for every process component is running?

If we do not specify the process TestActivity is running, will it also be able to start from another process?

Answer (score 2):

Application context is not belong to any process. but all process belong to the application.
Android application context is Singleton and therefore, you have only one of it for all usages.

If you start an Activity from a service or anything else which is not another Activity context you should use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag.

Usage is like:

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to launch activity from service, you should use PendingIntent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (YourActivity.class, getContext());
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), 0, intent, 0);
pi.send();
```

Where getContext () is a service's context

Comment: `getContext()` should be first parameter.